# How can print multiple pdf files by reading from source and send to printer

Tags: java, php, javascript, pdf

I already tested window.print() command for this purpose but it is not fulfill my requirement.
I also used print content of iframe in which source is pdf file but it is only work in chrome not in other browser.

I want to print pdf files automatically using code instead of open file and print it.
For example there are two files such as 1.pdf and 2.pdf in any directory and source is given then how can print both files using either javascript or php or both.

I already tested window.print() command for this purpose but it is not fulfill my requirement.

My required as image as:

[image]

Million thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to automatically print a PDF document using a printer on the computer of the person who is currently browsing the website?

Comment: Please paint a picture that describes what you want to do and add it to your question.

Comment: client has choice to select files and print.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue of merging multiple pdf or image or both by using imageMagick.
Using below command we can merge pdf and image as:

```
<?
$cmd = "test.pdf test.jpeg final.pdf";
exec("convert $cmd");
?>
```

After completed merging process, open final.pdf automatically using code then user can print it easily.

You can [find more](http://sanjeevkumarjha.com.np/resize-image-covert-image-merge-image-merge-pdf-using-imagemagick/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since most browsers, unlike google chrome (where it works) don't have a built in pdf viewer.

The printing of a pdf document is up to the pdf reader, whether or not it is installed as a browser plugin, not the browser.